# php-mysql voting system?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using the following script to build a php-mysql voting system (like the one in youtube) in my website. also i am using ajax to execute the php in newtest.php. I tested the php by it self and it worked just fine. Now I am using on mouse click in ajax to vote up or down but it is not working. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong ?(I am a beginner in ajax) . Also I want to return and display the current vote number updated automatically.

```
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar == "con1") {
    $db_host = "host";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_pass = "pass";
    $db_name = "phphitscounter";

    @mysql_connect ("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could Not Connect To The Database");
    @mysql_select_db ("$db_name") or die ("No Database");
    mysql_select_db("phphitscounter", @mysql_connect ("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass"));

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $Page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $pagenum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $Page);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM vote WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        echo "You have already voted";
    }
    else{
        echo "Thank you for voring";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote (ip, page, voteup, votedown) VALUES ('$ip', '$pagenum', 0, 0)");
        mysql_query("UPDATE vote SET voteup = voteup + 1 WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    }

    $voteup = mysql_query("SELECT voteup FROM vote WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    $results_voteup = mysql_fetch_array($voteup, MYSQL_NUM);
    print ($results_voteup[0]);
    echo "1";
}
else if ($contentVar == "con2") {
    $db_host = "host";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_pass = "pass";
    $db_name = "phphitscounter";

    @mysql_connect ("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could Not Connect To The Database");
    @mysql_select_db ("$db_name") or die ("No Database");
    mysql_select_db("phphitscounter", @mysql_connect ("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass"));

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $Page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $pagenum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $Page);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM vote WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        echo "You have already voted";
    }
    else {
        echo "Thank you for voring";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote (ip, page, voteup, votedown) VALUES ('$ip', '$pagenum', 0, 0)");
        mysql_query("UPDATE vote SET votedown = votedown + 1 WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    }

    $votedown = mysql_query("SELECT voteup FROM vote WHERE ip = '$ip' AND page = '$pagenum'");
    $results_votedown = mysql_fetch_array($votedown, MYSQL_NUM);
    print ($results_votedown[0]);
    echo "2";
}
```

the test.php page:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function swapContent(cv) {
        $("#myDiv").html('<img src="Assets/loading.gif" width="50" height="50"/>').show();
        var url = "scripts/newtest.php";
        $.post(url, {
            contentVar: cv
        }, function(data) {
            $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        });
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #myDiv {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 12px;
        border: #666 1px solid;
        background-color: #FAEEC5;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="Assets/like.png" href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');" />
    <img src="Assets/dislike.png" href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');" />
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
<img src="Assets/like.png" href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');"/>
<img src="Assets/dislike.png" href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');"/>
```

With:

```
<img src="Assets/like.png" href="#" id="up"/>
<img src="Assets/dislike.png" href="#"id="down"/>

<script>
$('#up').mousedown(function() {
swapContent('con1');
});

$('#down').mousedown(function() {
  swapContent('con2');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<img src="Assets/like.png" href="#" onClick="swapContent(1);"/>
<img src="Assets/dislike.png" href="#" onClick="swapContent(2);"/>

function swapContent(value){

$("#myDiv").html('<img src="Assets/loading.gif" width="50" height="50"/>').show();
var url = "scripts/newtest.php";
$.post(url, {contentVar: value} ,function(data) {
   $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
});


}
```